# Mongoose Schema how to change date.now whenever DB is updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How Can we change the value of `updated_at` whenever Data of DB is updated

Consider this to be my Mongoose Schema,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const locationDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    locationName: String,
    location: [{
        lat: Number,
        lng: Number
    }],
    news: [ {
        author: String, //or number
        title: String,
        description: String,
        url: String,
        urlToImage: String
    }],
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default:  Date.now
    }
})
```

From my Vaguely reading of Mongoose Docs, I did something like this

```
locationDataSchema.post('save', (next) => {
    console.log("here")
    this.locationName = this.locationName.toLowerCase();
    this.updated_at = Date.now()
 })
```

But this isn't being called whenever I create/update something in my mongoose Schema

Question: Can someone help me in figuring out how can I change

```
updated_at = Date.now()
```

Whenever user updates data in DB (similarly changing location Name to Lowercase)

Comment: Is this your required answer @noobiesatan

Comment: @Vignesh I tried something else but according the docs this looks correct

Comment: ok thank you but can I know what you did so that I can know if.

Comment: @Vignesh I write modular code, so I made updates_at as string and in my helper function -> Date.now()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current version of Mongoose (v4.x) has time stamping as a built-in option to a schema:

`var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema( {name: String}, {timestamps: true} );`

This option adds createdAt and updatedAt properties that are timestamped with a Date, and which does all the work for you. 
For more please look at

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps